# Displaying outline of municipalities where wind turbines are located

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

With this query, I get the outline of the department of Yonne in France and the points representing the wind turbines.

```
[out:json];
area["ref:INSEE"="89"]->.a;
rel(area.a)["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="6"];
out geom;
node(area.a)["power"="generator"]["generator:source"="wind"];
out geom;
```

[image: outline]

I would also like to obtain the outline of the municipalities where the wind turbines are located.

[image: outline of the municipalities]

Can you help me modify the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it in overpass turbo: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1vWa
. Explanations are inline...

```
[out:json]              //  json output format
[bbox:{{bbox}}];        //  restrict to current bounding box in overpass turbo

// find wind turbines
node["power"="generator"]["generator:source"="wind"];      

// and print them
out; 

// determine areas in which wind turbines are located
is_in; 

// determine corresponding boundary=adminsitrative ways and relations with admin level 6 or 8.
wr(pivot)["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"~"[68]"]; 

// and print boundaries
out geom;
```